# Waiting MySQL execution before rendering template

Tags: python, mysql, flask, async-await, synchronization

I am using Flask and MySQL. I have an issue with updated data **not** showing up after the execution.

Currently, I am deleting and redirecting back to the admin page so I may then have a refreshed version of the website. However, I still get old entries showing up in the table I have in the front end. After refreshing manually, everything works normally. The issue sometimes also happens with data simply not being sent to the front-end at all as a result of the template being rendered faster than the MySQL execution and an empty list being sent forward, I assume.

On Python I have:

```
@app.route("/admin")
def admin_main():
    query = "SELECT * FROM categories"
    conn.executing = True
    results = conn.exec_query(query)

    return render_template("src/admin.html", categories = results)


@app.route('/delete_category', methods = ['POST'])
def delete_category():
    id = request.form['category_id']
    query = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE cid = '{}'".format(id)
    conn.delete_query(query)
    return redirect("admin", code=302)
```

*admin_main* is the main page. I tried adding some sort of "semaphore" system, only executing once "conn.executing" would become false, but that did not work out either. I also tried playing around with async and await, but no luck ("The view function did not return a valid response").

I am somehow out of options in this case and do not really know how to treat the problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you tried adding some basic logging (or even, I hate to say it, print statements) to see whether the `results` value is actually correct or not before returning the rendered template, or ensuring other values are what you're expecting? You may be making assumptions about your program state that are leading you down the wrong troubleshooting path

Comment: The thing is that this works normally after refreshing. I can see the entries deleted in the database and also the redirection happening without any issue. Data correctly shows up in the table, but **only after** refreshing (this, after being redirected). I will try some more troubleshooting and see what's going on with the data once I get home but I do not think the problem is there, as it works occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the problem was not with the data not being properly read, but with the page not being refreshed. Though the console prints a GET request for the page, it does not direct since it is already on that same page.

The only workaround I am currently working on is socket.io implementation to have the content updated dynamically.